# How to config phpcs.xml to accept acronym with the CamelCaps rule?

Tags: php, phpcs, psr-1

I have the following error when I "phpcs" my code :

```
 223 | ERROR | Method name "Query::MySQLQueryBuilder" is not in camel
     |       | caps format
     |       | (PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps)
```

I would not to exclude the rule but just add a specification or ignore some values when there is an acronym like "SQL".

I want to do something like this (if possible) :

```
<rule ref="PSR1.Methods.CamelCapsMethodName.NotCamelCaps">
    <porperties>
        <property/>
    </porperties>
</rule>
```

*Thanks for your help.*